# Combinations and the vertical brother

Tags: riddle, word

> When the vector product politely greeted the king,
>
> and when the symbol of faith was with ribbon fit,
>
> we went silent for the kill.
>
> Hope you get the hint.

Comment: This doesn't rhyme. Is the [tag:rhyme] tag a mistake, or a hint that rhyming is involved somehow in the solution?

Comment: Not a hint. But isn't this a rhyme? Do king,fit,kill,hint not rhyme?

Comment: No. There's just assonance (same vowel each time), but not rhyme. Fill, kill, hill rhyme, and so do fit, kit, hit, but fit, kill, hint don't rhyme.

Comment: ahh, so the consonants must be the same too. Learning something everyday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aha. The word we need is

> CROSSBOW.

```
When the vector product politely greeted the king,
```

> the $\times$ made a bow;

```
and when the symbol of faith was with ribbon fit,
```

> the crucifix was tied with a bow;

```
we went silent for the kill.
```

> we shot our victim with a CROSSBOW.

As for the title,

> a Cartesian product (also denoted with a CROSS) involves taking all possible *combinations* of two or more things from given sets, and the ordinary bow could be considered a "brother" of the crossbow -- and is held *vertically*, unlike a crossbow. (Note: it took some prodding from OP in the comments before I understood the "vertical brother" part.)

Comment: Correct! How about the title?

Comment: Humorous, for sure :) A better title might've been rot13(Na naablrq oebgure, nf va PEBFF OEB)

Comment: I guess the combinations are a rot13(Pnegrfvna cebqhpg) but I confess I don't understand the "vertical brother" bit.

Comment: Correct again. The vertical brother describes the connection between the second word component and the whole word.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be a...

> permutation vector?

Explanation:

*When the vector product politely greeted the king,*

> The king may refer to a matrix

*and when the symbol of faith was with ribbon fit,*

> The ribbon may refer to the long square brackets for the vector notation.

*we went silent for the kill.*

> A vector product of a matrix and a permutation vector reorders it’s rows/columns which may be perceived as twisting its structure to kill

*Hope you get the hint.*

> Permutations and combinations are frequently discussed together in combinatorics. Hence, it could be described as its *vertical brother*.

Comment: Not the intended answer. There are some math concepts in the puzzle, but not as much.

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer

> CROSS?

*When the vector product politely greeted the king,*

> Vector product is also called a **cross** product.

*and when the symbol of faith was with ribbon fit,*

> The symbol of the Christian faith is a **cross**.

*we went silent for the kill.*

> Killing a sleeping vampire with a cross?

There might be more to it than this, though, because

> I haven't explained "politely greeted the king" or "with ribbon fit". Maybe the real solution is a longer word that just starts with cross.

Comment: Your last sentence is exactly correct! Actually, all of them except the 4th one.

Comment: @George I went AFK after your comment, came back to the computer and the correct answer was posted. Fair play to Gareth.

Comment: It was an easy one for you guys!